# Is it safe to install jetstream for an existing laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

I want to use jetstream for auth.
I create the project earlier and already worked on it. Now I want to use jetstream.
But in the official documentation of jetstream I found this warning:
"New Applications Only

Jetstream should only be installed into new Laravel applications. Attempting to install Jetstream into an existing Laravel application will result in unexpected behavior and issues."
[image]

Now I want suggestions that how I can use jetsteam without any issue in my existing project.

Comment: Uhhh as the documentation says, it should be installed into a new project only to avoid unexpected behaviour… why do you need to post a question here when the documentation actually tells you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

probably there should be no problem if you are using git . just commit your latest changes and add jet stream .
there is an issue on Jetstream GitHub page about it

> Please, give red visible warning for peoples, that Jetstream will overwrite your existing work, and it is meant to be install only on fresh installations.

[check it out](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/issues/398)

update :  
well , I have added Jetstream to my existing project which working on it for four months , there was a problem with font awesome Vue version which deleted that and going to add it again with newer version

[image]

, there was some bugs but was easy to resolve , so if you backup your project its totally ok and works fine , but you have to setup your project again with previous tasks you have done before